# What is "^@" character sequence means in file

Tags: linux, bash, character, vi

When I open a `/proc/PID/cmdline` file that stores `qemu-system_x86_64` process arguments, each space is changed by the `^@` character sequence.
It is possible to `cat cmdline | tr '\000' ' '`, that means that sequence corresponds to the `NUL` character.

Why this sequence appears there instead of a whitespace? Is it possible to get
an ASCII value for the escape sequence using `shell` commands?

Comment: Which file format? If "all of them", too broad.

Comment: There is no special meaning to this character sequence *in a file*. Some text editors like vi(m) show the null character this way.

Comment: In C, which *nix utilities tend to be written in, each string is terminated by a binary zero byte.    The command-line (often called `argv[]`) is an array of those strings, that is a chunk of memory with a binary zero between each command-line argument.  The space is used for tokenising by shells to make it user friendly, it is not there otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) `^@`, it is used to show control characters 0 to 31 and 127 in different editors or viewers: `vi`, `less`.

> ```
> ^@ (64) : 0  NUL
> ^A (65) : 1  SOH
> ...
> ^Z (90) : 26 SUB
> ^[ (91) : 27 ESC
> ^\ (92) : 28 FS
> ^] (93) : 29 GS
> ^^ (94) : 30 RS
> ^_ (95) : 31 US
>
> ^? (63) : 127 DEL
> ```

To see the exact sequence in a file `od` for octal dump utility can be used :

- examples

to see characters and octal values

```
od -c your_file
```

to see hexadecimal values

```
od -t x1 your_file
```

to see decimal values

```
od -t u1 your_file
```

to see all 3 at the same time

```
od -c -t x1 -t u1 your_file
```